# How can I check if the query is empty?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to move to the other frame if the query result is empty. How can I check if the query is empty?

```
String query2 ="Select* from biletbilgileri where Filminİsmi='" + filmKoltuk + "'" + 
                        " " + "and" + " " + "SeansTarihi='" + SeansTarihKoltuk + "'" + " " + "and" + " " +
                                "SeansSaati='" + SeansSaatKoltuk + "'";
                        Statement stmt1=conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery(query2);
                        rs1.next();

                        if(rs1==null)
                        {                   
                            tesekkurEkrani1.setVisible(true);
                            tesekkurEkrani1.setSize(1000,500);                              }
                        else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This chair isn't empty!");  
                        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When composing SQL queries it’s important to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/java) any and all user-data to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This code exposes you to severe risk and should not be deployed.

Comment: "Empty" meaning "didn't get any results"? You probably want to check how many rows your `ResultSet` contains. It's not going to suddenly `==null` because `rs1` is a `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use SQL [`count(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) in the query `select count(*) from biletbilgileri ...`. If the returned value is 0, there are no rows returned by your original query.

```
String query2 = "select count(*) from biletbilgileri ...";
ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(query2);
rs1.next();
int count = rs1.getInt(1);
if (count == 0) {
  // empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call rs1.next();, it returns a boolean.  If the boolean is false, it means there are no more rows.  so I think you want to do this:

```
    boolean notEmpty = rs1.next();
        if(notEmpty )
        {
```